# Is there a SIMPLE way to store passwords in Ionic2?

Tags: android, cordova, security, ionic2, cordova-nativestorage

Native Android (and I guess iOS too) apps can easily store app private data (such as login credentials) to the private app data storage. This method is considerably secure (unless the user has rooted their phone...), but I don't see how can I reach this storage from cordova (Ionic 2).

Current methods available:

- NativeStorage plugin - uses Android Context to keep data (shared data!) without encryption.
- SecureStorage plugin - requires the phone to be locked with pin/password, a thing that you just cannot require from an ordinary user.
- LocalStorage plugin - even less secure than the NativeStorage
- SqlStorage - Really? SQL queries for my 3 secure fields. Don't think so. Too much work...

Am I missing anything?

EDIT: This question is based on the wrong impression that NativeStorage is not secure enough. After reviewing the plugin I think that it might not be as right.
The question was primarily raised because of the plugin's "new feature" (that was not yet exposed - but the code is there) providing password protected data. 
Yet using the app's private shared data should be one of the best options, with the lack of proper other option (as noted above)...

Comment: Why do you want to store the password in the device? After login you can just store a token (with an expiration date) instead of the password...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually another way - using cordova-plugin-file API - but it is quite a pain to use, especially if you plan to debug it in the browser ("ionic serve" CLI has an open issue with cordova plugins).

[the plugin "documentation"](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

[the apache github source folder](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

[usage - but in JavaScript](https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/)